# Rename XSL without save prompt using PowerShell

Tags: excel, powershell

I am a novice to PowerShell and have been working on the following script to look through a directory for XLS and XLSX files.  Afterwards, it would get the creation date of each file and rename the filename with the creation date appended to the end.

This script works fine for XLSX files.  However when XLS files are encountered, the is save prompt: **"Want to save your changes to xxx.xls?"**

How can I get rid of this save prompt.  Below is my code.  Thank you:

```
Param(
$path = "C:\Excel",  
[array]$include = @("*.xlsx","*.xls")
)

$application = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$application.Visible = $false
$binding = "System.Reflection.BindingFlags" -as [type] 
[ref]$SaveOption = "microsoft.office.interop.Excel.WdSaveOptions" -as [type]

## Get documents
$docs = Get-childitem -path $Path -Recurse -Include $include    

foreach($doc in $docs)
{
try 
{
    ## Get document properties:
        $document = $application.Workbooks.Open($doc.fullname)
        $BuiltinProperties = $document.BuiltInDocumentProperties
        $pn = [System.__ComObject].invokemember("item",$binding::GetProperty,$null,$BuiltinProperties,"Creation Date") 
        $value = [System.__ComObject].invokemember("value",$binding::GetProperty,$null,$pn,$null)

    ## Clean up
        $document.close([ref]$saveOption::wdDoNotSaveChanges)

        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($BuiltinProperties) | Out-Null
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($document) | Out-Null
        Remove-Variable -Name document, BuiltinProperties

    ## Rename document:

            $date=$value.ToString('yyyyMMdd');
            $strippedFileName = $doc.BaseName;
            $extension = $doc.Extension;
            #write-host $strippedFileName;
            $newName = "$strippedFileName" +"_" + "$date"+ "$extension";
            write-host $newName;
            Rename-Item $doc $newName

}
catch
{ 
    write-host "Rename failed."
        $_
} 
}

$application.quit()
$application.Workbooks.Close()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($application) | Out-Null
```

Comment: Try `$document.Saved = $true` right before `$document.close()`

Comment: Thank you Mathias!  That worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this old kb article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/213428/how-to-suppress-save-changes-prompt-when-you-close-a-workbook-in-excel), you can trick excel into not prompting you by setting the `Saved` property on the workbook to `true`, so I would try:

```
$document.Saved = $true
$document.close([ref]$saveOption::wdDoNotSaveChanges)
```